# Como armazenar as Strings retornadas do método split() em variáveis diferentes?

Tags: java

Possuo o seguinte problema: cadastro uma pessoa informando o Nome e CPF, neste formato **"João Medeiros - 123456789-00"**, e armazeno numa variável do tipo *String*. Utilizei o método `split()` para "separar" o Nome e o CPF.

Como faço para armazenar o Nome na variável `String nome`, e o CPF na variável `String CPF`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ao usar o método `split` sua string vira um array, depois é só criar as variáveis e setar qual posição do array você atribui de valor para aquela variável.

```
String frase = "João Medeiros - 123456789-00";
String array[] = frase.split(" - ");
String Name = array[0]; //Aqui vem o nome como primeira posição
String CPF = array[1]; //Aqui vem o CPF como segunda posição
```

Comment: Deu certo sua solução!!!